# Variables In PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, variables, feedback, preference

In my android application i want to make a feedback dialog that will show the second time the application is started. 
How can i do this ?
Can i do it by variables in a PreferenceActivity. If the a variable in the preference activity is edit by feks ++; will this be the result of the variable next time the app is started ?

**Edit:** 
I dont get any of the suggested answers to work, can i create a text file on the ext or internal store the first time the app is started and check if the file exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs;
  private static final String PREF_LAUNCH_COUNTER = "launch_counter";
  private int mLaunchCount = 0;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    mSharedPrefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (savedState != null) {
      mLaunchCount = savedState.getInt(PREF_LAUNCH_COUNTER, 1);
    } else {
      mLaunchCount = mSharedPrefs.getInt(PREF_LAUNCH_COUNTER, 1);
      if(mLaunchCount > 1) {
        //code to handle when the app was launched after the first time.
      } else {
        //code for when the app was launched for the first time..
      }
      mSharedPrefs.edit().putInt(PREF_LAUNCH_COUNTER, mLaunchCount++);

    }

  }
  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     outState.putInt(PREF_LAUNCH_COUNTER, mLaunchCount);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, variables do not persist through activity restarts, because the entire object is garbage collected and recreated.

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store data that must be persisted between application launches.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda of a barbarian solution, but it did not have Eclipse or and Android phone close to me.
You can do something like that I think :

```
protected boolean isSecondLaunchTime() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int time = settings.getInt("launchTimes", 1);

    if(time==1 || time>2) return false;

    settings.edit().putString("launchTimes", ++time);
    settings.edit().commit();

    if(time==2) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Good luck !